# Find not event.target using querySelectorAll() :not()

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have a group of elements that have 'click' event listeners attached.

When triggered, I want to find which elements are **not** the target of the event.

I've been using querySelectorAll() with :not(), but this selects all of the elements including the target:

https://codepen.io/wrgt1/pen/rNMqbpm?editors=1010

```js
const thumbnail = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");

thumbnail.forEach(function(thumb) {
  thumb.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const target = "." + e.target.classList[1];
    const notTarget = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail:not(target)");
    console.log(target);
    console.log(notTarget);
  });
});
```

```css
#thumbnails {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.thumbnail {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #FF7400;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbnails">
  <div class="thumbnail project1">Project 1</div>
  <div class="thumbnail project2">Project 2</div>
  <div class="thumbnail project3">Project 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You did not insert the _value_ of the variable `target` into your selector, you put the _static text_ `target` into it. None of your `.thumbnail` elements has the _tag name_ `target`, so this selects all of them …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`target` is a variable and needs to be concatenated into the selector:

```js
const thumbnail = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");

thumbnail.forEach(function(thumb) {
  thumb.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const target = "." + e.target.classList[1];
    const notTarget = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail:not(" + target + ")");
    console.log(target);
    console.log(notTarget);
  });
});
```

```css
#thumbnails {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.thumbnail {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #FF7400;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbnails">
  <div class="thumbnail project1">Project 1</div>
  <div class="thumbnail project2">Project 2</div>
  <div class="thumbnail project3">Project 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That will break if the project class moves

Comment: @mplungjan yep of course, but just a direct correction of the OP code. Your solution is of course the one we'd all pick!

Answer (score 1):

If you delegate you can do this

```js
const container = document.getElementById("thumbnails");
container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("div"); // handle clicks inside the divs too
  if (tgt.classList.contains("thumbnail")) {
    console.log(tgt.textContent, "clicked");
    const thumbs = [...container.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail")]; // here in case thumbs are added
    const others = thumbs.filter(thumb => thumb !== tgt); // this is what you wanted
    const texts = others.map(thumb => thumb.textContent);
    console.log(texts, "not clicked");
  }
});
```

```css
#thumbnails {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.thumbnail {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #FF7400;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbnails">
  <div class="thumbnail project1">Project 1</div>
  <div class="thumbnail project2">Project 2</div>
  <div class="thumbnail project3">Project 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is select all the other elements that match your criteria, then run through them and exclude the event.target, i.e. the current element.

`const allSiblings= allThumbnailsArray.filter( element => element != target);`

Made a codepen for you here:

https://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/mdrzYYO?editors=1010

You shouldn't use a new query with a "not" selector because that's not reliable as classes are not made for identifying elements, but classifying or grouping them(i.e. if you have 2 sections with thumbnails, you'll exclude thumbnail project4 from both of them) if you're working with classes, and it's also more costly(slow) than processing an array.

Comment: I already [suggested that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65704199/295783) but delegated and posted the code here instead using the snippet editor

Comment: Who says that :not() was “not reliable with classes”? You might have some specific case in mind here, but as an across-the-board statement, this is simply not true.

Comment: @mplungjan well, haven't noticed that but this answer is more geared towards the reasoning behind the change, not just slapping the code together for a quick reply. Also, your answer seems to be incorrect as it uses the event handler differently, which means clicking other children or grand children (and so on) or clicking the blank space between the thumbnails triggers the function which can lead to issues.

Comment: @CBroe true, I might've expressed my point incorrectly, sorry about that.

Comment: @PaulGhiran That clicking inside or outside took less time to fix than writing this comment. I delegate which is recommended over adding a listener to every single element and not handling if new elements are added later

Comment: No, it really isn't. It's better in some cases, and worse in others. Delegation isn't a silver bullet. (nor is it a part of the question)

Comment: Whenever there is a loop and addEventListener, the silver bullet IS delegation - especially if you need to process siblings